# calculation on rotated polygon

Tags: javascript, rotation, polygon

i have to calculate a path over a polygon.
The polygon points are known in gps coordinates (lat, lng).

The way I do it:
create a rectangle around the polygon (find min lat/lng and max lat/lng)
in this rectangle then i start at min(lat,lng) and go all the way to the upright corner. first moving in fixed x direction and when reached the max x, move fixed y up and go back.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsrDP.jpg).

So this is good. However i want to be able to choose the (starting) angle of the path. probably i need to rotate the polygon, calculate a new rectangle and calculate it again. however I don't manage to do a rotation based on a given angle.

The current code:

```
// calculate the rectangle
var bottomLeft = 
{ 
    lat: points[0].lat,
    lng: points[0].lng
};
var topRight = 
{ 
    lat: points[0].lat,
    lng: points[0].lng
};  

for(var i = 1; i < points.length; i++)
{
    if (points[i].lat < bottomLeft.lat)
    {
        bottomLeft.lat = points[i].lat;
    }
    else if (points[i].lat > topRight.lat)
    {
        topRight.lat = points[i].lat;
    }

    if (points[i].lng < bottomLeft.lng)
    {
        bottomLeft.lng = points[i].lng;
    }
    else if (points[i].lng > topRight.lng)
    {
        topRight.lng = points[i].lng;
    }
}

//start position
var currentPosition =
{
    lat: bottomLeft.lat,
    lng: bottomLeft.lng
}

//calculate points
var outputPoints = [];
var direction = 0;
while (currentPosition.lat <= topRight.lat && currentPosition.lng <= topRight.lng)
{
    if(pointInPoly(points, currentPosition))
    {
        outputPoints.push(copy(currentPosition));
    }

    if (direction == 0)
    {   
        if(currentPosition.lat + stepX < topRight.lat)
        {
            currentPosition.lat += stepX;
        }
        else if(currentPosition.lng + stepY < topRight.lng)
        {
            currentPosition.lng += stepY;
            direction = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if(currentPosition.lat - stepX > bottomLeft.lat)
        {
            currentPosition.lat -= stepX;
        }
        else if(currentPosition.lng + stepY < topRight.lng)
        {
            currentPosition.lng += stepY;
            direction = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
return outputPoints;
```

}

So, the user should be able to give an angle and then the grid has to be calculated taking the angle into account. Even though the polygon may have to translated/rotated for the calculation, obviously the polygon needs to be at the exact same spot as where it was made and the red line (path) has to fit right in.

to add the line to the map I use the following code:

```
function showLine(polygon) {
if(!isConvex(polygon))
{
    console.log("cannot calculate outputPoints, polygon not convex");
    return;
}
var outputPoints = calculatePoints(polygon._latlngs, 0.001,0.85,0.85)
var polyline = L.polyline(outputPoints, {color: 'red', opacity: 2, weight: 2});
polyline.addTo(Window.map);
console.log("done");
```

}

Any thoughts how I can manage to do this?

With kind regards,

Racusthor

Answer (score 0):

Instead of increasing x and then y, you have to increment both with a value that depends on your angle.

`x += stepX`

becomes

`x += stepX * cos(angle)
 y += stepX * sin(angle)`

and

`y += stepY`

becomes

`x -= stepY * sin(angle)
 y += stepY * cos(angle)`

Comment: I thought about this, but I am not sure where the starting points is then. (in order to cover the whole polygon)